# A secure way to verify instance is running within AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am a novice to this community and have just started the development with AWS java APIs. My question is following:

Is there a foolproof secure way of verifying that the underlying instance from which the AWS Java API program is running is indeed running on an instance that's in AWS?

My requirement is to unambiguously verify that a given instance is on AWS and user is not running it from their local environment outside AWS. And I want to do this using AWS Java APIs. Any pointers/suggestion on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the host system controls the executable code, there is always the possibility that a user can remove your checks, emulate AWS, or any other part of the system.

There is no foolproof way to do what you want to do, because of what is commonly referred to as [the DRM problem](https://superuser.com/questions/14224/how-can-i-explain-why-drm-cannot-work).

Answer (score 0):

As Michael J Gray mentioned, there is no foolproof way to do this due to spoofing or check eliminating (basically someone copying your code without the checks, modifying the checks, or figuring out a way to get past them through some other means).

If you're not concerned with the possibility of someone somehow bypassing your checks, and simply want to check if it's on an instance before running to prevent errors that could come up due to running outside of the instance, you can do a check for the instance's ID using the code below:

```
public String retrieveInstanceId() throws IOException {
    String EC2Id = null;
    String inputLine;
    URL EC2MetaData = new URL("http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id");
    URLConnection EC2MD = EC2MetaData.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(EC2MD.getInputStream()));
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        EC2Id = inputLine;
    }
    in.close();
    return EC2Id;
}
```

This method will return null (after about 15-30 seconds) if the program is not run on an EC2 instance.  Additionally, if you are running on an instance, you can retrieve info about the instance that may allow you to verify that it is your instance, such as reading instance-specific tags attached to the instance ID (this could get you around the emulation/"spoofing" issue, if done right).

You can check instance info using the following:

```
try {
    myEC2Id = retrieveInstanceId();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace(getErrorStream());
}
DescribeInstancesRequest describeInstanceRequest = new DescribeInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds(myEC2Id);
DescribeInstancesResult describeInstanceResult = ec2.describeInstances(describeInstanceRequest);
String firstTag = describeInstanceResult.getReservations().get(0).getInstances().get(0).getTags().get(0);
System.out.println(firstTag);
```

If they figure out a way to get around your checks all together, this will not help, and pretty much nothing will in that case.

**Edit:** You can find the list of available instance information that can be retrieved by checking the get commands for instances, [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/Instance.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot DGolberg and Michael J. Gray for your quick replies. My thoughts were going in similar direction but thought to verify.